# try catch on ExecutionTimeout not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-upload, executiontimeout

This one has been the source of much torment for me! I am using the global `ExecutionTimeout` of 110 seconds for my application. One particular page generates a great number of unhandled exceptions as it contains a `FileUpload` control.

Now here is the problem...I know how to limit the file size and the execution timeout in the web.config using the following declarations.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" executionTimeout="600" />
```

The problem I have is right here:

```
    'Check file size
    Dim fileSize As Integer
    Try
        fileSize = FileUpload1.FileBytes.Length
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Display message to user...
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

The very process of checking the file length quite frequently throws an exception, and that exception isn't caught gracefully in the above `try, catch`, it seems to defer to the application level exception handling in the global.asax.

I'm pretty sure I can't check the file size on the client-side, I don't want to keep bumping up the `maxRequestLength` and `executionTimeout`, all I'm looking to do is catch those timeouts on the page and display a message. Is this possible?

**EDIT ---**

To better illustrate the problem here, try running the following code (assumes your default executionTimeout is 110 seconds).

```
    Try
        system.threading.thread.sleep(120000)
    Catch ex As Exception
        response.write("Error caught!!")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

Make sure debug is switched off. The catch block won't work and you'll end up with an unhandled `System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out` error, this I have yet to figure out?

Comment: So what is wrong with the posted code? I don't really understand your problem

Comment: My guess is the is some unmanaged code behind the FileUpload and they elude try catch.  But only a comment and a guess.

Comment: The problem is the catch doesn't work. If you substitute `fileSize = FileUpload1.FileBytes.Length` for `System.threading.thread.sleep(120000)` the catch block gets ignored and you end up with an unhandled executiontimeout error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code on the page isn't directly throwing the exception here, hence why it's not getting caught in the `try, catch`. The application monitors and intervenes when a script takes too long to execute, so when the exception is raised at the application level we need to defer to the global.asax.

The solution involves trapping the error in the Global.asax `Application_Error` block then response.redirecting back to the originating page with the error type appended to the query string.

```
 Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim exc As Exception = Server.GetLastError
        Dim context As HttpContext = DirectCast(sender, HttpApplication).Context

        Dim uri As String = context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery

        If uri.Contains("users/account.aspx") Then
            Response.Redirect(context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery & "&err=" & exc.GetType().ToString)
        End If
End Sub
```

You can then check in the page load for any `err` querystring value then display the error accordingly on the page.